# Dataflow WriteToParquet fails with no clear message: "Worflow Failed"

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I've already read these posts:

- [Google Cloud Dataflow - From PubSub to Parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017832/google-cloud-dataflow-from-pubsub-to-parquet)
- [Google Dataflow "Workflow failed" with no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877822/google-dataflow-workflow-failed-with-no-reason)

They were helpful and I ended up creating something like this for pub/sub messages like: `{"id": "1"}` (just for testing):

```py
subscription = f"projects/{project}/subscriptions/test-subscriber"
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
   records = p | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
   _ = records | 'Write' >> beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet(
            'gs://<bucket>/parquet/output/new',
            pa.schema([('id', pa.string())]),
            file_name_suffix=".parquet"
        )
```

I can only see the error "Workflow failed". But only for DataflowRunner, for DirectRunner I have no problems. Here the "run" command:

```
python code/dataflow/pubsub_to_gcs.py \
      --project=${PROJECT_NAME} \
      --output_path=gs://"${BUCKET_NAME}"/dataflow_output \
      --region=${REGION} \
      --job_name=testdataflow \
      --runner=DataflowRunner \
      --staging_location gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/staging_location \
      --temp_location=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/temp \
```

Here are the logs for this job (the first rows are the last occurences):

```
insertId,"labels.""dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id""","labels.""dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name""","labels.""dataflow.googleapis.com/log_type""","labels.""dataflow.googleapis.com/region""",logName,receiveTimestamp,resource.labels.job_id,resource.labels.job_name,resource.labels.project_id,resource.labels.region,resource.labels.step_id,resource.type,severity,textPayload,timestamp
kj98obbko,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,system,us-west1,projects/<proj>/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message,2021-01-13T14:39:46.649539202Z,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,504796790819,us-west1,,dataflow_step,INFO,Worker pool stopped.,2021-01-13T14:39:45.784300690Z
kj98obbkn,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,system,us-west1,projects/<proj>/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message,2021-01-13T14:39:46.649539202Z,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,504796790819,us-west1,,dataflow_step,DEBUG,Cleaning up.,2021-01-13T14:39:45.751440904Z
kj98obbkm,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,system,us-west1,projects/<proj>/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message,2021-01-13T14:39:46.649539202Z,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,504796790819,us-west1,,dataflow_step,ERROR,Workflow failed.,2021-01-13T14:39:45.733187585Z
kj98obbkl,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,system,us-west1,projects/<proj>/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message,2021-01-13T14:39:46.649539202Z,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,504796790819,us-west1,,dataflow_step,DEBUG,Fusing consumer WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite/_DataflowIterableAsMultimapSideInput(MapToVoidKey2.out.0)/StreamingPCollectionViewWriter into WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite/_DataflowIterableAsMultimapSideInput(MapToVoidKey2.out.0)/Values,2021-01-13T14:39:45.666536683Z
kj98obbkk,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,system,us-west1,projects/<proj>/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message,2021-01-13T14:39:46.649539202Z,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,504796790819,us-west1,,dataflow_step,DEBUG,Fusing consumer WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite/_DataflowIterableAsMultimapSideInput(MapToVoidKey2.out.0)/Values into WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite/_DataflowIterableAsMultimapSideInput(MapToVoidKey2.out.0)/GroupByKey/MergeBuckets,2021-01-13T14:39:45.651338237Z
kj98obbkj,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,system,us-west1,projects/<proj>/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message,2021-01-13T14:39:46.649539202Z,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,504796790819,us-west1,,dataflow_step,DEBUG,Fusing consumer WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite/_DataflowIterableAsMultimapSideInput(MapToVoidKey2.out.0)/GroupByKey/MergeBuckets into WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite/_DataflowIterableAsMultimapSideInput(MapToVoidKey2.out.0)/GroupByKey/ReadStream,2021-01-13T14:39:45.635839235Z
kj98obbki,2021-01-13_06_39_40-5574094972724851911,testdataflow,system,us-west1,projects/<proj>
```

For now, I gave up using dataflow, but if someone has any idea where should I check, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are these all the logs from your job? In the Cloud Logs Viewer there should be a dropdown that lets you filter by label. For example, in your snippet all the log messages seem to be `dataflow.googleapis.com/job-message` logs, but that dropdown allows you to select "All logs" which will show more log messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and I fixed it by going through all the logs related to the job. In my case what was causing the job to fail is that the dependencies are not getting installed. I would suggest you check the logs to see if the dependencies are getting installed fine.